# build dependencies while building C extension

Tags: ruby

I have written a standalone shared C library and I am writing a C extension for Ruby that uses this library.

I have the library source in one directory and the extension source in another directory. In general, these directories are arbitrary.

I need to build the library when the extension is built. I am using `mkmf` to generate the extension's `Makefile`, but I found no way to accomplish what I need using `mkmf`.

Please help.

EDIT:

here is my `extconf.rb`:

```
require 'mkmf'
NAME = 'MyExtension'
dir_config NAME
create_makefile NAME
```

I need to build the shared library as part of the process, and then load the library in my extension. Unless I find a way to do that, just including the source and statically compiling it into the extension would work too. Also, I can make a gem with the extension if it is easier...

Comment: Add your `extconf.rb` please? Please clarify - are you creating a stand-alone library that ships separately (and need to link it to which: lib in development, or a version you have packaged and installed), or want to include the library source with your Ruby C extension and have the Ruby project compile it directly? Finally, I'd like to know if this is for a gem (probably not relevant, but most of my experience with C extensions is with gems).

Comment: I can only advice to the the *passenger* gem, probably it will enlight the proper process.

Comment: And if you already have the **Makefile** for the library, you can just run the library build process from from `extconf.rb`.